# Java thread stops working and no Exception or Throwable is thrown

Tags: java, multithreading

I usually run my program with about 4 threads and anywhere between 1 hour to 10 hours after the program is running some threads just stop and do nothing, I have my program around Exception and Throwable block and I also have a uncaughtException for the thread and nothing gets added to my log files about any errors. How can I find what is causing the threads to stop?

EDIT

Here is the basic structure of my code

Below is the code for setting the uncaughtException block

```
                newThread.setName("Thread" + totalNumberOfThreads);
                newThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
                    {
                        Main.logger.info("ERROR! An exception occurred in " + t.getName() + ". Cause: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                newThread.start();
```

And this is the basic structure of the thread

```
@Override
public void run()
{               
  while (true)
  {
    try
    {               
      //a long section of code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Main.logger.info(threadName + ": " + e);
    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
      Main.logger.info(threadName + ": " + "Throwable: " + t);
    }
    finally
    {      
      //some code to close connections.. ect..
    }
  } // end while
}
```

Comment: [Deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) are the immidiate suspects. It could be very tricky to determine if the program is going to have one or not. Is the program working OK when running with a single thread? What synchronizations do you use between threads?

Comment: What do you mean, you have "a uncaughtException for the thread"?

Comment: Before starting the thread I have      newThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
  {
    Main.logger.info("ERROR! An exception occurred in " + t.getName() + ". Cause: " + e.getMessage());
  }
});

Comment: unfortunately I can't paste the whole code its very long and I don't own the code, I'm just working on it, but I have edited my question to show the structure of the program.

Comment: @Arya: I don't understand why you think it is an exception thrown - if no exception is shown? Care to elaborate? :|

Comment: Sorry, when you say "stop" do you mean they are still in the thread-list but seem to not be running?  They are blocked on something?  The uncaught exception handler will only show if the thread exits from `run()` because of throwing.

Comment: @Gary the way I wrote this is that when each thread is doing something is prints the name of the thread and the task its doing and it all gets logged using log4j, and say if had 4 threads after a while I only see that thread 1,3 and 4 are working according to the logs, and nothing about thread3

Comment: @Arya: Another possible issue is if your logger uses a writer that was not `close()`d

Comment: I'd learn how to do thread-dumps to see what they are doing: http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5/CQ5SystemAdministration/TakeThreadDump.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I find what is causing the threads to stop?

Do you know for a fact that the threads have stopped? As mentioned they might be blocked. You can use either [`jstack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) to see if they are active or for closer inspection start the program with remote debugging enabled and attach a debugger when you feel they have stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running the program in a debugger, which would let you inspect the state of the threads.

You can also use the built-in `Ctrl-Break` or `Ctrl-\`mechanism in Java - see [Troubleshooting Hanging or Looping Processes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/hangloop.html), which will cause the HotSpot VM to print a thread dump, including thread state.

Comment: Running with a debugger seldom solves synchronization bugs. See [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)

Comment: How do you know it's a synchronisation bug until you look?

Comment: The symptom is of a deadlock: `4 threads and anywhere between 1 hour to 10 hours after the program is running some threads just stop and do nothing ....  and nothing gets added to my log files about any errors`. It just screams deadlocks

Comment: YMMV. I've solved several synchronisation issues in the debugger. It depends on whether it's a subtle timing issue that the debugger may influence, or an issue that will reliably occur sooner or later regardless of exact timings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem just screams **[DeadLock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)** - it shows all the classic symptoms for one.

A deadlock is when thread A is waiting to thread B to finish and free some resource (lock), while thread B is waiting to thread A to finish and free some resource as well.

[More information on deadlocks can be found in the java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html)

This results in both threads stop execution and waiting for nothing.

Finding if a program indeed has a deadlock could be very tricky in some cases, even when using a program that is designed to detect dead-locks, the usage of the program could "solve the problem" temporary. for more details see [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Sometimes (though not always) the best way to detect the dead lock is to look at the abstraction of the program, and try to check all dependecies between threads - and see where a possible collision in dependecies might happen.

P.S. Another common syncrhonzation problem is [Data Race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing)

Comment: Do deadlocks occur when I use the join() method for threads? because I'm not using .join() and I just read the link and I'm not using synchronized either. I'm using the HTMLUnit library can that be causing this problem?

Comment: @Arya: They might happen when you use `join()` or the `synchronized` keyword, or some blocking data structure (Like [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)), or for almost any syncrhonizaion between different threads actually..

Comment: I edited my last comment before yours loaded. If the library I'm using has a deadlock problem there is not much I can do is there?

Comment: @Arya: I have no idea not familiar with that library - it really depends on how you use everything.. Is there any shared data between threads? (Are they writing to the same resource? reading from the same resource? sending data to each other?)

Comment: @Arya Also another possible issue could be if your thread has written to a writer that was not `close()`d. Is it the issue there?

Comment: I have all my data members set as volatile protected TYPE NAME, so nothing is shared between the threads. I'm not sure what you mean by it was not closed() the way I write the error is by Main.logger.info(threadName + ": " + "Throwable: " + t);

Answer (score 0):

First, I would look into ExecutorService and breaking your code up into a Callable.  This would allow you to run it in a thread with the ability to return a value or let exceptions rise.  Then, you could restart it if problems occur.

It's a LARGE code smell whenever code catches Exception and / or Throwable.  Any exceptions beyond the checked exceptions, should be thrown.  If you use the callable pattern like mentioned above, you can check what you're getting, log it, and restart (if necessary).